# Rename a table name in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have created a custom Module using **[Ultimate Module Creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9)** and it has created tables named **`xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice`** and **`xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice_store`**.

I would like to rename these tabels to **`xe_customer_product_price`** and **`xe_customer_product_price_store`**. I don't know which files have to be edited.

Can anyone guide through the steps?

---

Below is my **Config.xml**

---

```
<modules>
    <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice</module>
                <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
            <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Block</class>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
            <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Helper</class>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
    </helpers>

<events>
    <catalog_product_get_final_price>
        <observers>
            <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>get_final_price</method>
            </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_get_final_price>
    <catalog_product_load_after>
        <observers>
            <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>get_product_load_after</method>
            </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>
    <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
        <observers>
            <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>get_product_collection_load_after</method>
            </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_price_observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
</events>






    <models>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
            <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource</resourceModel>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
            <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <customerproductprice>
                    <table>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice</table>
                </customerproductprice>
                <customerproductprice_store>
                    <table>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice_store</table>
                </customerproductprice_store>
            </entities>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
                <file>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice.xml</file>
            </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
                <files>
                    <default>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <global_search>
        <customerproductprice>
            <class>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice/adminhtml_search_customerproductprice</class>
            <acl>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice</acl>
        </customerproductprice>
    </global_search>
</adminhtml>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice before="Mage_Adminhtml">Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Adminhtml</Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice</module>
                <frontName>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice</frontName>
            </args>
        </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
                <file>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice.xml</file>
            </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
                <files>
                    <default>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<default>
    <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        <customerproductprice>
            <breadcrumbs>1</breadcrumbs>
        </customerproductprice>
    </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
</default>
```

Comment: Can you please add code for your config.xml file?

Comment: @John i have updated my question with Config.xml

Comment: Can you add your module version code(full config.xml)? It will require to create upgrade script.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i have updated with full Config.xml

Comment: @Guruprasad, did you get the solution of your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function available in Magento to rename a table.
Check, `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::renameTable($oldTableName, $newTableName, $schemaName = null)`

Update your `models` tag in **config.xml** by below.

```
<models>
    <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource</resourceModel>
    </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
    <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
        <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <customerproductprice>
                <table>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice</table>
            </customerproductprice>
            <customerproductprice_store>
                <table>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_customerproductprice_store</table>
            </customerproductprice_store>
            <customerproductprice_new>
                <table>xe_customer_product_price</table>
            </customerproductprice_new>
            <customerproductprice_store_new>
                <table>xe_customer_product_price_store</table>
            </customerproductprice_store_new>
        </entities>
    </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
</models>
```

Update your module's version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 in below lines.

```
<modules>
    <Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice>
</modules>
```

Now create a new file in your **sql/xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_setup/upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php** with below code

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$this->getConnection()->renameTable($this->getTable('customerproductprice'),$this->getTable('customerproductprice_new'));
$this->getConnection()->renameTable($this->getTable('customerproductprice_store'),$this->getTable('customerproductprice_store_new'));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Now go to admin panel and refresh your cache. Once you are done with refreshing your cache, update your `models` section again to below.

```
<models>
    <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
        <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource</resourceModel>
    </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice>
    <xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
        <class>Xpresselectricals_CustomerProductPrice_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <customerproductprice>
                <table>xe_customer_product_price</table>
            </customerproductprice>
            <customerproductprice_store>
                <table>xe_customer_product_price_store</table>
            </customerproductprice_store>
        </entities>
    </xpresselectricals_customerproductprice_resource>
</models>
```

Comment: this didnt work, it is not creating the new table in the database

Comment: It will not create new tables, it will rename your old tables to new tables. Also you need to refresh your cache to run the upgrade script

Comment: i did the same, but it dint rename the tables

Comment: oh yes, there is one more thing you need to do. please check updated code.

Comment: Hi @jaimin your updated answer worked!! thank you